# What may be causing AssetBundle.LoadAsset to freeze the game and device?

Tags: unity, android, assetbundle

My game uses AssetBundles, all located locally in StreamingAssets (although on Android they're automatically put in the .obb file). We use them for almost everything - monsters, areas, music, and... frame-by-frame 2D animations.

When loading one such animation, the relevant logic is more or less this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFrames; i++)
{
    var sprite = bundle.LoadAsset<Sprite>(PathForFrame(i));
    loadedFrames.Add(sprite);
}
```

This works just fine. It has worked fine on every platform - consoles, standalone, iOS... But on Android, there is one seemingly random case in which the game will freeze when calling `LoadAsset` (but the music keeps playing, and it doesn't seem like the OS detects this as a crash or unresponsiveness).

I am at a loss to understand what's causing the freeze, because:

1. Logcat doesn't display anything interesting when it happens (even with full logging and development mode), not on the app itself nor on the device in general. It does help me pinpoint which specific frame did the game try to load before freezing, but...
2. ... The problem doesn't seem to revolve around a particular animation frame, or a particular AssetBundle. Every time I've managed to reproduce this freeze, it has been a different animation. And to clarify, frames/bundles that caused the freeze before, work fine in later sessions - that is, the freeze is seemingly random.
3. Even though logcat doesn't show any obvious errors, it is clear that "something" is off about the device itself, because going back Home you can still hear the game's music, and it's not always responsive enough to kill the application (but eventually you can). This does seem to hint that it may be related to memory or a file handle limit, perhaps. However...
4. ... Sometimes, I managed to reproduce this very early on. So I'm not fully convinced that it is actually a memory leak issue. Moreover, this is something that hasn't happened in any of the other platforms, so overall I feel like the memory management of the game is fine, unless Android has gimmicks that I wasn't aware of.
5. To further believe that it's not a memory leak of some sort, I actually run the same automated test each session where the game loads and unloads the exact same areas/animations in sequence endlessly, and there are sessions where it'll freeze quite early, while other sessions can last for hours.
6. I have also tested keeping a cache of every AssetBundle in the game and never unloading it, just to confirm that it's not an IO problem when reading from the Android OS. Sure enough, the problem persists, strongly suggesting that it's not related to the way I am loading the AssetBundles but rather whatever is going on inside `LoadAsset`.

---

I had a feeling that it may have been related to the tight loop, as if doing too many loading operations in the same frame. Replacing the logic for `LoadAllAssets<Sprite>()` didn't seem to change anything (I guess internally it's the same as the loop).

So, I've tried to modify it to work as a coroutine, something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFrames; i++)
{
    var sprite = bundle.LoadAsset<Sprite>(PathForFrame(i));
    loadedFrames.Add(sprite);
    yield return null;
}
```

Obviously overkill and everything is very slow now, but after a lot of testing I managed to reproduce again the freeze - so I guess it wasn't the excessive number of calls after all.

I haven't tested it with the Async versions yet, due to other logistic issues, but from the previous test I doubt that parallelism is the right solution.

Other possible approaches are to use Addressables, or Android AssetPacks, or even just throw everything into Resources, but ideally I just want to understand what's happening to `LoadAsset` and have it work like all other platforms. Does anyone have any insight on what may be behind this?

---

- Unity 2020.3.7f1
- Target Android SDK: 29
- API Levels: 19+
- So far I've only been testing on a Galaxy S10+, but again, it runs perfectly fine on all other platforms and several iOS devices.

---

**Update 1**

Out of curiosity I shoved those animation frames into `Resources`. My tests have been running for hours and they haven't frozen the game yet.

It is a bit puzzling because from what I understand `Resources` ends up being an AssetBundle anyway... But I guess, it's just one big bundle. This might hint that there really is some kind of issue regarding the number of bundles present.

Putting my stuff in `Resources` isn't ideal - I'm using AssetBundles specifically to not use `Resources` to begin with.